# Почему теряются стили при преобразованит html в pdf с помощью laravel-dompdf

Tags: laravel

Скажите, пожалуйста, html преобразовываем в pdf с помощью laravel-dompdf,  но стили совсем не те(точнее расположение), может ли проблема быть, что какие-либо параметры css не поддерживаются плагином? например flex. Если эту же hml закинуть на сайт(который найден в поисковике), куда вставляется html и можно ее скачать - там все ок, как нужно преобразовывает

Comment: Я очень долго мучался с этим пакетом при выводе таблицы. Пробуйте разные варианты, в том числе замените flex. Или используйте другое решение. Самое лучшее что я использовал - это [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/), но нужно ставить на сервер.

Answer (score 5):

Причина этого в том, что dompdf не может открыть внешние файлы CSS..

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/635718)

Comment: @finally, вроде по смыслу как ответ подходит. Плюсанул.

Comment: @Uranus все таки у ответа должно быть какое никакое оформление и логическое заключение